# MySQL Service Stopped on its own

Tags: mysql, railo

Over the last two nights, my MySQL service has just stopped on its own. I have had no issues before for the last year and there have been no database changes within the last two days. 
Could this be a hack? Can someone be stopping the service somehow by exploiting a possible weakpoint in my website? I would like to believe my system is pretty secure against things like SQL injection attacks, but perhaps there are other ways?

I am running MySQL 5.1.11 and Railo 3.2.1.000 final

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant lines from the log.

Comment: Try looking into the mysql error log, perhaps at `/var/log/mysql/mysqld.err`. If it's not there, see the config file for the error log location.

Comment: @Emil Vikström: Which log would that be?

Comment: @ypercube: So I did a full search of my harddrive and found no file called mysqld.err?? Is that possible?

Comment: It's sometimes called `myweb.com.err` or otherwise. See your mysql config file (usually `my.cnf`). Are you using Windows or Linux ?

Comment: @ypercube:If I look under MYSQL Admin startup variables, I see that Error Logfile Name was NOT checked. So I checked it and gave it a file name. Is this the file that should show me the info I'm looking for should it happen again?

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: See  the Error Log page on MySQL Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html

Comment: Also (on the previous link): `On Windows, error output is always written to the .err file if --console is not given.

In addition, on Windows, events and error messages are written to the Windows Event Log within the Application log. Entries marked as Warning and Note are written to the Event Log, but informational messages (such as information statements from individual storage engines) are not copied to the Event Log. The log entries have a source of MySQL. You cannot disable writing information to the Windows Event Log. `

Comment: In my windows box, I have a `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data\kps06.err` file and another at `C:\mysql\data\kps06.err` (from the second mysql installation). So, if you are on Windows, check your `MySQL installation folder\data\ ` for an  `*.err` file.

Answer (score 0):

check your mysql configuration for the log location.  look for:

> log_error=

if that isn't set, you can either add it to your my.cnf, or you can just set it at runtime.  I haven't tried the later personally, but the docs indicate that it's doable under 5.1.x.

seems odd that you wouldn't have *any* logs, though.  Try:

> find /var/log -name mysql*

and then look in /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog, and check your crontab entries to make sure they're not doing something unexpected; MySQL won't die without making a lot of noise.  Your question is unfortunately impossible to answer without more information.